# How to allign text on ribbon button?

Tags: c++, mfc

as adding a ribbon button, I am also supplying the name for it. It is performing its desired action, but placement of string is absurd. It should not be over the image, but under it. Any suggestions please. Adding code snippet and screenshot.

```
RibbonButtonProp* mRibbonProperties;
bool m_bsetlargeimage = FALSE;
if (ButtonProp.Lookup(m_nMenuItemID, mRibbonProperties) != 0)
{
    if (ButtonProp[m_nMenuItemID]->m_bIfSmallButton == FALSE)
    {
        m_PanelImage.SetImageSize(CSize(32, 32));
        m_PanelImage.Load(ButtonProp[m_nMenuItemID]->m_nImageResourceId);
        m_bsetlargeimage = TRUE;
    }
    else
    {
        m_PanelImage.SetImageSize(CSize(16, 16));
        m_PanelImage.Load(ButtonProp[m_nMenuItemID]->m_nImageResourceId);
        m_bsetlargeimage = FALSE;
    }

    pRibbonButton = new CMFCRibbonButton(m_nMenuItemID, m_strMenuItemName, m_PanelImage.ExtractIcon(ButtonProp[m_nMenuItemID]->m_nImageIndex));
    pRibbonButton->SetAlwaysLargeImage(m_bsetlargeimage);
```

[Print should be just under the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F1KNw.png)

Comment: I looked into afxribbonbutton.cpp, and found that image size for const CSize sizeImageLarge = m_pParent->GetImageSize(TRUE); is returned only 16, 15 pixels, wherelse it should be 40,40. Any ideas why it is not reading the correct lengths?

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to change this. This is the way ribbons are shown and drawn.

A button text in "large-mode" is always drawn below the icon. I see nothing in the code to change this behavior AND I would never change this, because it is the default behavior people want/expect to see in a standard ribbon.

Comment: How can i make sure that "large-mode" is enabled? i am assuming that the call SetAlwaysLargeImage(True) solves this? please correct if I am wrong.

Comment: Yes! SetAlwaysLargeImage(True) does the job.

Answer (score 0):

Earlier
AddCategory(m_strMenuName, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, i, NULL);

Now
AddCategory(m_strMenuName, NULL, NULL, CSize(16,16), CSize(32, 32), i, NULL);

Explanation: It was placing the text assuming that all the image size is small only as it was not defined already while calling create.